# how to connect to localhost with this code?

Tags: c#, mysql, localhost

i have a problem with this c# code. I need to connect it to mysql, localhost database, Please give me the correct code to [**connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=root;User ID=root;Password=";** ] connect to the localhost.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            **connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=localhost;User ID=root;Password=";** 
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: The connection string you posted is quite generic. Is that really your connection string?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `System.Data.SqlClient` in your connection which I think used for SQL Server. Your connection string is also not for MySQL Database. Try this one.

```
using System.Data.Odbc;


string connectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost;  
DATABASE=dbname; UID=myuserid; PASSWORD=mypassword;OPTION=3; POOLING=false;";

OdbcConnection DBCon = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
if (DBCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    DBCon.Close();
}
DBCon.Open();
MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
DBCon.Close();
```

Change the ODBC Driver version depending on what you are using.

Change the DATABASE, UID and PASSWORD value.

Comment: No to forget to connect to local MySQL server only by: user@127.0.0.1....Also create the user in MySQL before: Create user user@127.0.0.1 identifie by '************Password*******';

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have tagged MySql connection, so preferably you want to use the mysql connection. Which you can download / install here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Also it is wise to use the try-catch-finally approach. So that when the connection opens, and some exception occurs, the connection will always close afterwards.

As another addition, you could put the connectionstring in an `App.Config` or `Web.Config` so that you have the connectionstring available in all your files, and only have to adjust it in one place.

hope this will help you

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; //using the mysql dll

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDb;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPass";
            MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //shows what error actually occurs
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: + This is the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) you need

Answer (score 0):

It should look a little more like this:

```
connetionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=<Name of the Database>;User ID=root;Password=";
```

The data source property is where you put the network location, the initial catalog is the name of the database (in mysql).

Edit:

However, I believe you'll need the mysql libraries, which I notice you're not `using` at the beginning.
Get them from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

The Data.SqlClient namespace is typically how you'd connect to MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConStr = "Server=localhost;Database=YourDB;Username=YourUsername;Password=YourPassword";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConStr);

        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully");
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
            {
              MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to DataBase");
            }

    }
```